# Google Webmaster is not Accepting my Sitemap

Tags: seo, sitemap, robots.txt, google-search-console

After setting my Google Webmaster account and verified my website, i failed to add my sitemap to it. It was issuing the following error.

[image]

**I tried to do the following:**

1. I removed the robots.txt and still didn't work.
2. I tried to verify my sitemap on http://www.validome.org/google/validate and it got reported as valid.
3. I checked the sitemap and my URL several times for errors and everything seemed to be alright.

**For Reference:**

**My sitemap.xml is as follows:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<url>
  <loc>http://www.myDomain.com/</loc>
  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
  <priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.myDomain.com/about/</loc>
  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
  <priority>0.90</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.myDomain.com/help.php</loc>
  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
  <priority>0.90</priority>
</url>
</urlset>
```

**My Robots.txt is as follows:**

```
User-agent: ia_archiver
Disallow: /

User-agent: duggmirror
Disallow: /

User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/

Sitemap: http://www.myDomain.com/sitemap.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the problem was from Google servers. I didn't change anything, just left the whole topic for a week and tried again. Everything seems to be working fine now.

Sometimes due to some major updates or Google busy servers, the acceptance of sitemaps takes more time that the usual rates. For those people who are facing similar problems, just wait for some days and give it another shot before complaining in Google forums and such.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some nice reference for you problem with htaccess rules against bot :

http://www.widexl.com/tutorials/htaccess.html

http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=27809

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not quite sure i understood what you mean. Do you mean that i have problem with my htaccess? Have you faced this problem before? I would be glad if you can elaborate a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something really effective for your need :

- Replace your robots.txt rules by this one :

  ```
  User-agent: *
  Allow: /
  Sitemap: http://www.myDomain.com/sitemap.xml
  ```
- And add this to your .htaccess

  ```
  #Block ia_archiver & duggmirror
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*.ia_archiver|duggmirror* [NC]
      RewriteRule .* - [F]


  #Block cgi access
      <filesMatch "^php5?\.(ini|cgi)$">
          Order Deny,Allow
          Deny from All
          Allow from env=REDIRECT_STATUS
      </filesMatch>
  ```

Comment: You mentioned a good note there! Thanks